# Angular 2 Export Service from Module

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a directory structure set up like this:

```
 app 
  |- core
  |   |_identity
  |   |    |_identity.service.ts
  |   |_ http
  |        |_apiClient.service.ts (service for interacting with my api)
  |-user
  |   |- models
  |   |    |-user.ts
  |   |- services
  |   |     | - user.service.ts
  |   |-listComponent
  |
  |-tenant
      |-models
      |   |-tenant.ts
      |- services
           |- tenant.service.ts
      ....
```

Both my tenant.service and my user.service inject my ApiClient object (that extends the http service). The problem is, to reference it, I have to add

`import {ApiClient} from '../../../core/http/apiClient.service'`

in all of my components that want to inject it. I have a core.module defined (and imported into my app.module) and would like to be able to reference my ApiClient without having to know the directory structure (i.e. I would like to be able to import it like the http service with `import {ApiClient} from '@core/http'`.

Comment: That is how the import system works. It's not a problem. If you are using Visual Studio Code, install the Auto Import Extension - which will generate these imports for you. Very handy!! Or a similar extension for whatever IDE you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how Module resolution works in Typescript.

> TypeScript will mimic the Node.js run-time resolution strategy in
>   order to locate definition files for modules at compile-time

Read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

You may create a Angular library for your common functionality and install it using `package.json` so that the common module is inside `node_modules` folder like other libraries. then you may use all the exported types easily without knowing  directory paths like,

```
 import { ApiClient } from 'MyLib';
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How does this handwaving about "you may create a Angular library" help? They aren't libraries they're modules and it's relatively complicated to have that module export a service. "You can create a library" is hardly helpful.

Comment: @RickO'Shea, I hope you are not mixing [Angular Modules and Javascript Modules](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#whats-the-difference-between-angular-and-javascript-modules), they are different the solution i suggested is to simply create JS Modules, you may look into the link I have added in the solution. Hope it helps you as well, Cheers!!

Comment: @Brian, Such strong words.. :-) , I hope you have a better way of solving this, Can you elaborate to why do you think it is ludicrous to install a library via npm? Or better if you can add your answer, Cheers!!

Comment: @Brian, Who says if you put your resources inside node modules it can not be AOT compiled and can't use tree shaking? , I hope you are not saying if you use multitude of libraries listed at [Angular Resources](https://angular.io/resources) (look into Data Libraries and UI Component libraries) they will not be AOT compiled and cant be tree shaken, (Well it also depends on how different libraries have been bundled, but most of them are correctly configured and give us packages in a format which can use these techniques), Hope it clarifies your concerns, Cheers!!

Comment: You can easily bundle services in a Module and inject it, that should not be issue, look into [Angular Material library](https://github.com/angular/material2), or [Angular Fire library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), they bundle many services which you want to use in your application, You can also look into Angular router they also provide services which we inject in our components, Cheers!

Comment: Well it depends on your use case, Also it is not just about saving to type some import statements, Let's say you are working for a large organization and you want to share few libraries among multiple applications,  without giving a consideration to where in your folder structure you are saving your core library, the best place to keep it is node modules. If you see [Nrwl Extensions for Angular](https://nrwl.io/nx), they solely depend on this concept, Hope it helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: @Brian, would you be gracious enough to +1 my answer, so that it is not considered as bad answer :-) , Cheers!!